# Validating Uk 10 digit number to begin with 0 PHP

Tags: javascript, php

```
function is_validNumber($chkNum) {
$regexp = '/^[0-9\+\-\)\(\d\s]{7,}$/';
if(preg_match($regexp, $chkNum))
  return true;
else
  return false;
}
```

n above code, I created a function wherein the input text for the phone number will accept minimum of 7 characters (this only includes numbers and characters + and -).

i need the 0 in start of the number and after it there will be 10 more digits to go. i want to do this validation. how can we do that. let me know if you guys have any solution for you.

thanks

Comment: Try some simple plugins

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `$regexp = '/^[0-9\+\-\)\(\d\s]{7,}$/';` does not match what you want to do.

If you want 0 to be the first character and the next 10 to be numbers (exactly 10, I suppose, judging from your question), use:

```
$regexp = '/^0\d{10}$/':
```